# How to pull shorter flex content up into row above

Tags: css, flexbox

For narrow content I want to have the layout:

```
[ CONTENT ONE ] 
[ CONTENT ONE ] 
[ CONTENT TWO ]
[ CONTENT TWO ]
[ CONTENT TWO ]
[ CONTENT TWO ]
[ CONTENT THREE]
[ CONTENT THREE]
[ CONTENT THREE]
[ CONTENT THREE]
[ CONTENT THREE]
```

But if the container widens I want to have:

```
[ CONTENT ONE ]   [ CONTENT TWO]
[ CONTENT ONE ]   [ CONTENT TWO]
[ CONTENT THREE ] [ CONTENT TWO]
[ CONTENT THREE ] [ CONTENT TWO]
[ CONTENT THREE ]
```

Is this layout possible with flex?  The way I have it ONE is the same height as TWO in the wide view but I want to be able to pull THREE up so it is above the bottom of TWO

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need a media query for this where you change the `order` properties.

Comment: This looks more like 3 `float`s to me than a flexbox

Comment: @MrLister I cannot use media queries unfortunately because the number of columns is based on the size of the variable width container not the window.

Comment: @ııı No, with floats you get the problem that content three is not immediately below content one, since content two is higher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that layout with flexbox and the `order` property. Is there another way? Perhaps. Search for "masonry layout" solutions; however most will probably involve Javascript to detect dimensions rather than being pure css-only.

To your specific need, if you can't use media queries, then you'll have to use JS to monitor the parent element width and make adjustments accordingly. There's other posts on that topic.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/vborEw?editors=1100)

```css
#container {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* this is needed to force columns to wrap sideways (to the right),
     otherwise this will always be a straight column */
  max-height: 200px;
    
}

.group {
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#group1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  order: 1;
}


#group2 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  
  /* setting order to 3, which forces this element to the end of the list.
  Since 'column wrap' is set on the container, and it has a max-height, the list wraps horizontally forcing this element to appear on the right side. */
  order: 3;
}


#group3 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  order: 2;
}

/* example media query, resetting list to regular ordered column */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #container {
    
      /* set to normal column view */
      flex-flow: column;
  }
  
  #group2 {
    
    order: 2;
    /* You'll see that group2 and group3 now both have 'order:2', in this case the HTML structure takes precedence. */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="group1" class="group">
    <div class"item">1A</div>
    <div class"item">1B</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="group2" class="group">
    <div class"item">2A</div>
    <div class"item">2B</div>
    <div class"item">2C</div>
    <div class"item">2D</div>
  </div>
    
  <div id="group3" class="group">
    <div class"item">3A</div>
    <div class"item">3B</div>
    <div class"item">3C</div>
    <div class"item">3D</div>
    <div class"item">3E</div>
  </div>
```